# Active Record model query in self loop executes differently in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I am building the Facebook Oauth by using the `facebook-omniauth` gem. I wrote this method to create the user based on the auth data.

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
      user.username =  check_username(auth.info.email)
      user.remote_avatar_url = get_image_url(auth)
      user.skip_confirmation!
    end
  end
```

and for `username` generation I wrote this method where it check that the given username is currently present or not.

```
def self.check_username(value)
    username = value.split("@").first
    byebug 
    while(User.where(username: username).exists?)
      username += rand(100).to_s
    end
    username
  end
```

There is very strange error is happening or may be I am not aware of something. Here when I try to execute `User.where(username: username)` which should be results into the 
`select * from users where username=username`
it is actually executing

```
User.where(username: username)
  CACHE (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`provider` = 'google_oauth2' AND `users`.`uid` = '101977206788010441641' AND `users`.`username` = 'ashjambhulkar'
```

even when I try to simply fetch all the users record it gives

```
(byebug) User.all
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`provider` = 'google_oauth2' AND `users`.`uid` = '101977206788010441641'  [["provider", "google_oauth2"], ["uid", "101977241641"]]
#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

how can i modify this query that it will get executed normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are calling that method inside the `first_or_create` block.

`first_or_create` is literally that `first || create(*args, &block)`. Now when `create` is called with a block all queries inside that block are scoped to the current scope via a method called [`scoping`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-scoping)

> Docs State: "Scope all queries to the current scope.
>   ...
>   Please check unscoped if you want to remove all previous scopes (including the default_scope) during the execution of a block.

With an example of:

```
Comment.where(post_id: 1).scoping do
  Comment.first
end
=> SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = 1 ORDER BY "comments"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

You should be able to resolve this via

```
def self.check_username(value)
  username = value.split("@").first
  while(User.unscoped.where(username: username).exists?)
    username += rand(100).to_s
  end
  username
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I got one more error in the same context I am trying to create avatar using `gem 'avatarly'`. but whenever I try to create Avatarly object within the check_username method it like this `Avatarly.generate_avatar(text, opts={})`
it always end up like User::Avatarly how can i resolve this.

Comment: You should be able to change this `Avatarly.generate_avatar(text, opts={})` to `::Avatarly.generate_avatar(text, opts={})` the preceding colons `::` makes the reference a top level reference thus escaping the scope of `User`